Can a quantum state be prepared to encode two pieces of information, allowing a choice of which to read?
Can I prepare a quantum state encoded with, let's say, two bits, but it's only possible to read only one of the bits? But the catch is that it's possible to choose which bit you want to read; after that, the state collapses in such a way that you cannot determine the other bit with certainty. Is something like this possible, or will I be breaking some fundamental law?
More formally, if such a protocol exists:
A prepares a state with these two bits and gives it to B, and C wants to verify if B does indeed have the state prepared by A, so C will query about either of the two bits and then verify from A if the answer is correct or incorrect.

This is a protocol known as "oblivious transfer".

@NorbertSchuch I'm not looking for a transfer protocol; I'm asking if it's possible to prepare such a state in which you can choose if you want to learn about the 1st or the 2nd bit but not both.

If you know the preparation, you know both bits of information, so the setting in which this makes sense is for one party to prepare the state and someone else to try and read the information. It's a transfer of information!

Have you read about information causality? (https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2292) Does this achieve what you're after?

@DaftWullie I wanted to know if something like the below is possible:
A prepares a state with these two bits and gives it to B, and C wants to verify if B does indeed have the state prepared by A, so C will query about either of the two bits and then verify from A if the answer is correct or incorrect.

It is impossible to have two measurements in different basis, both with deterministic results.

Why do you need Alice, Bob, and Charlie? Can’t you do everything between Alice and Bob? Is Alice sending two qubits to Bob, but then Charlie measures only one of the two qubits?

@MarkSpinelli Alice sends some state, which contains information about both the bits. Now to verify that Bob didn't create this state on his own by taking a measurement and then just creating another state, Charlie will query for either one of the bits, which ensures that Bob couldn't have measured the state before. You can of course do it between Alice and Bob, but I wanted to know if it was possible between 3 people with Charlie not knowing any secret about the created state.

There's certain limitations to the possibility to do oblivious transfer quantumly, and this will also limit what you want to do.

Impossibility of your protocol with almost deterministic outcomes
Without loss of generality, the protocol you seek is:

Alice sends $\rho\left(s_0,s_1\right)$ to Bob, with $s_0$ and $s_1$ being two secrets bits. The function $\rho(\cdot,\cdot)$ is public.
Charlie chooses a bit $b$ and send it to Bob.
Bob can perform two measurements $M^0$ and $M^1$, applies $M^b$ on $\rho\left(s_0,s_1\right)$ and returns the outcome. Measuring with $M^0$ should return $s_0$ with probability $1-\varepsilon$, and measuring with $M^1$ should return $s_1$ with probability $1-\varepsilon$.

However, as per the Almost As Good As New Lemma, after measuring using $M^b$, Bob will be able to recover a state that is $\sqrt{\varepsilon}$-close to $\rho\left(s_0,s_1\right)$ in trace distance, which will then allow him to measure using $M^{1-b}$ and get the other bitstring with high probability.
Thus, the only hope is that the measurement outcome isn't deterministic. Or, saying it differently, Bob can't be able to choose which bit he wants to read.

A note about oblivious transfer
An oblivious transfer protocol is a protocol between two parties, Alice and Bob, where:

Alice has two messages $m_0$ and $m_1$
Bob can learn either $m_b$ or $m_{1-b}$ but not both
Alice can't know which message Bob learnt

In you case, you have the relaxation that it doesn't matter whether Alice learns which bit she shared with Bob in your case. Still, it should be possible to apply existing oblivious transfer protocols to your case.
As per this review unfortunately, oblivious transfer is impossible without additional assumptions. It is however possible, if we can assume (choose one):

Bob has only a noisy quantum memory, or a bounded one
Quantum-secure one-way functions exist

Note that this doesn't magically circumvent the previously stated impossibility: the reason why we can still achieve this functionality is because Alice and Bob are allowed to exchange multiple quantum states and classical messages before Bob learn $m_b$. Thus, this achieves the desired functionality of Bob learning one of $m_0$ or $m_1$, but not the fact that he should get them directly from a measurement.

Your proof is incorrect. As a counterexample, consider the trivial strategy $\rho(s_0,s_1) = |s_0s_1\rangle\langle s_0 s_1|$, with $M^0 = {|0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I, |1\rangle\langle 1| \otimes I}$ and $M^1 = {I \otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|, I \otimes |1\rangle\langle 1|}$. You're assuming that the measurement must be rank-1 projective, and this is too restrictive.

@MateusAraújo Indeed, nice catch! This counters the first argument, but not the second though, does it?

Indeed, now everything is fine.

@MateusAraújo Thanks for the proofreading!

Nayak's bound allows us to do better than classical (randomly guessing), we can choose either bit and read it correctly w.p. $\cos^2(\pi/8)$
